# request-response pattern mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request, response

Is the request-response pattern in Asp.net (Webforms) the same as (or similar to) the 'model' being passed and returned in the MVC world. Basically, should there still be a need to use the request / response (i.e. creating seperate request and response classes) pattern if all the request/response classes are doing is containing some properties related to request or response and can actually be placed in the model, e.g.

```
LoginRequest.cs contains   
string Username { get; set; }

LoginResponse.cs contains 
string AuthenticationTicket { get; set; }
```

whereas LoginModel.cs would have

```
string Username { get; set; }
string AuthenticationTicket { get; set; }
```

Which is better in to use in the MVC world ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One could argue that depending on the level you look at it, they are both the same since you have a request (postback with context parameters/model binded through model binder) and a response (changing the response object/rendering the view based on viewmodel) in every request, but on another level they are fundamentally different since webforms was conceived to be natural to windows forms developers and MVC is, IMO, a more mature and with better SoC architecture for web frameworks.

When dealing with MVC apps I usually go for one class that represents the view model and another one that make sense for the request so in a user details scenario I would have something like this:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}

public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string Fullname {get;set;}
    public string LastLogin {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model) 
{
    /* do whatever you need */

    return new LoginViewModel { ... };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need the Request/Response DTOs when dealing with WCF Scenarios. The Request entity should be serializable and contains information that shd be discrete to the MVC View. On the other hand, the view model contains information bound to the relevant view. hope this help!